# Python regex return binary value based on compiled pattern

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have a regex to extract numbers from a given string

```
import re
compiled_pattern = re.compile(r'\d+')
sample = "Hello world 32"

print(compiled_pattern.findall(sample))
```

output:

```
['32']
```

But is it possible to return `1` if there is a number in the string and `0` otherwise? Essentially `1` if there is a match for the pattern in the string and `0` otherwise. So in this case, the op should be `1`. Any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: `print (1 if compiled_pattern.search(sample) else 0)`?

Comment: @41686d6564 please post it as the answer and I can accept it.

Comment: You can go ahead and accept the existing answer if it helps you; that's fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can test for whether regex found the pattern or not.  For example:

```
def match_or_not(sample):
    compiled_pattern = re.compile(r'\d+')
    match = compiled_pattern.findall(sample)
    return 1 if match else 0

for sample in ["Hello world 32", "Hello again"]:
    print(match_or_not(sample))
```